# Android videoview causes blocking UI elements

Tags: android, android-videoview

Hi in my android application I am using videoview for streaming my videos. I face very unwanted behaviour from my videoview. The scenario is like this. I have activity A and activity B. Activity A has one simple button and on click of that button I am starting activity B which contains videoview and starts playing video as soon as it start my activity. So my observation is like this: Once I start Activity B it will call `setVideoURI` and `start()`. there are few callback methods one of them is `setOnPreparedListener`. when I call `start()` after some time It is executing `setOnPreparedListener` and after that it will start playing video. But in between before executing `setOnPreparedListener` if I come back to Activity A it will block that activity UI for some time. But if I wait till `setOnPreparedListener` get executes and then come back to Activity A then its working properly. This is not happening with all devices only with google devices like moto g and nexus. But I tried with htc or intel device it is working properly. My code looks like :

```
  VideoView mVideoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);  

              //Creating MediaController  
      MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
          mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);          

        //specify the location of media file  
     Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://abcExample.com/playlist.m3u8");          

        //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView  
     mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);  
     mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);          
     mVideoView.requestFocus();  
     mVideoView.start();  


     mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                Log.i("this is video view sample ... ", "this is video view sample ... this is on error listener ");
                return true;
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                Log.i("this is video view sample ... ", "this is video view sample ... this is on prepared listener ");
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                Log.i("this is video view sample ... ", "this is video view sample ... this is on complete listener ");
            }
        });
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone knows about this?

Comment: I have tested with both mp4 and hls videos. For hls videos it is giving this issue otherwise for mp4 its is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same behaviour with videoview. I was looking for a solution but i didn't find anything. Maybe, It's possible that making a new task fix that issue. I'll try it